# Is it possible to program with Rails and Python together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, python-3.x

I would like to know if it is possible to program in both Rails and Python. Can I use the Rails framework as a back-end and also program with Python?

Comment: You should look into frameworks specific for python. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#Python

Comment: You actually want to program in Ruby and Python. With Ruby you want to use the Rails framework.

Comment: maybe write a C layer connection bridge between the 2, or maybe something like it already exists, but it sounds tricky...

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, since you can run Rails on the JVM with JRuby, you can interop with any JVM language, including Jython.

Do keep in mind that Rails is designed to be used with Ruby, and makes heavy use of Ruby Blocks, which are cumbersome to emulate in Python. So, if you want to do background tasks with Python, it's OK, but if you plan to use it for anything that requires lots of direct interaction with the Rails framework you're gonna have a bad time.